# rxjs catch errors of individual observables in the chain

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to call 2 APIs one after another, and I want show different errors if any of them fails. Originally I tried this, but if first observable fails, I am getting 2 errors displayed:

```
of(null).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.service.getSomething1()),
    catchError(error => {
        this.showError('Error with Something1');
        return throwError(() => error);
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.service.getSomething2()),
    catchError(error => {
        this.showError('Error with Something2');
        return throwError(() => error);
    })
)
```

I can make above code work properly if I nest pipes:

```
of(null).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.service.getSomething1().pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.showError('Error with Something1');
                return throwError(() => error);
            })
        );
    }),
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.service.getSomething2().pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.showError('Error with Something2');
                return throwError(() => error);
            })
        )
    })
)
```

Can I get the same effect without nested pipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By returning empty Observable I can achieve what I wanted:

```
of(null).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.service.getSomething1()),
    catchError(error => {
        this.showError('Error with Something1');
        return of();
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.service.getSomething2()),
    catchError(error => {
        this.showError('Error with Something2');
        return of();
    })
)
```

Side effect: final Observable will be empty instead of in failed state. This is ok in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the request to run in order (that is, if `getSomething1()` doesn't have to run before `getSomething2()`) you could use `forkJoin` like this:

```
const something1$ = this.service.getSomething1();
const something2$ = this.service.getSomething2();

const handleError = source => catchError(err => {
   const sourceMsg = source === 1 ? 'Error with Something1' : 'Error with Something2';
   this.showError(sourceMsg);
   return throwError(() => err);
});

forkJoin([
    something1$.pipe(handleError(1)),
    something2$.pipe(handleError(2))
]).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
    // Handle the data
});
```

UPDATE:

To execute the requests in order, you can use `concatMap`:

```
const something1$ = this.service.getSomething1().pipe(catchError(err => {
    this.showError('Error with Something1');
    return throwError(() => err);
}));

const something2$ = this.service.getSomething2().pipe(catchError(err => {
    this.showError('Error with Something2');
    return throwError(() => err);
}));

something1$
    .pipe(
        concatMap(res1 => {
            // Handle the data from the first request

            return something2$;
        })
    )
    .subscribe(res2 => {
        // Handle the data from the second request
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need requests to run in order

Comment: I updated my solution. You would need to use nested pipes in order to do what you want.

Comment: I come up with solution without nesting pipes

Answer (score 1):

seeing that the return value of the observable does not matter, why not try:

```js
import { of, Observable, ignoreElements, catchError, concat, tap } from 'rxjs';

function invertError(obs: Observable<any>, errorMessage){
  return obs.pipe(ignoreElements(), catchError(err => of(errorMessage)))
}
// then
concat(
  invertError(this.service.getSomething1(), "Error with Something1"),
  invertError(this.service.getSomething2(), "Error with Something2"),
).pipe(tap(errorMessage => this.showError(error)))
```

the idea is to create an observable that extract only error message, then handle it however needed

concat is used here to replace switchMap for setting the sequence

Comment: This can work, but I like my solution more. I still need to process values returned by service methods, and this will add nesting here.